# Logarithmic colorbar in matplotlib color plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan, colorbar, logarithm

I've been trying to change tha labels and my colorbar to Logarithmic scale but I can't. I used this comand:

```
plt.pcolor(xx, yy, paco, cmap='RdBu',norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())
```

I tried to put vmin and vmax but nothing, some of my files have nan values. In fact the first file which get in to the comand has nan in all the values. And python gives me this

```
ValueError: minvalue must be positive
```

Maybe I have to ignore the nan values?, any advice?
this is the final result:
[image]

Comment: Logarithms only work for strictly positive numbers. NaN's are ignored automatically.

Comment: and what's worng then? my data is one array of float64(61,93)

Comment: Maybe print out `paco.min()`?  Also, if `paco` is all NaN's, it's probably better to skip the plot.